# Not able to load obj in <a-frame> for ar.js

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

Not able to load obj file in following html file for ar.js despite giving the correct paths:

```
<script src=”https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src=”https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

<body style=’margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;’>
  <a-scene embedded arjs=’sourceType: webcam;’>
      <a-marker preset=’hiro’>
        <!-- Adding an OBJ file to an AR Project-->
        <a-entity 
            obj-model=”obj: url(https://rishavjayswal.github.io/augmented-reality/resources/couch.obj); 
            mtl: url(https://rishavjayswal.github.io/augmented-reality/resources/couch.mtl)”>
        </a-entity>

      </a-marker>
  <a-entity camera>
  </a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Getting

> GET https://rishavjayswal.github.io/augmented-reality/%E2%80%9Dhttps://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js%22 net::ERR_ABORTED

after running. Tried with relative paths for obj and mtl file also:

> /resources/couch.obj

Can open the link here: https://rishavjayswal.github.io/augmented-reality/

Comment: What text editor are you using? If you're using `’` and `”` "pretty" quotes, I'm guessing you're trying to write code in word? That, or you copied the code from a wordpress blog post that had pretty quotes enabled. Those are not valid quotation marks for HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model loads just fine. This is a working example in glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/excellent-face?path=index.html:13:19

I see you are mixing types of quotes around your attribute values. Your HTML is not valid. Use straight double quotes: `"`

In your obj-model attribute you are using `”` and in your arjs attribute you are using `’`